# Databricks INIT script errors with wget

Tags: azure-databricks

I am trying to write an init script for a Databricks server. I have included a wget command which works from a Databricks Jupyter notebook. However when I include the command into an init script the init script fails and I do not know why.

Here is the script which I am using:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt install libwayland-server0 -y
pip3 install selenium==3.141 pandas webdriver-manager pyvirtualdisplay msedge-selenium-tools
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable main"
```

Does anybody have an idea why the last commands are not working?

Cheers

Comment: enable logging to DBFS & find what is the error - there is a separate init script log... Also, please note that not all directories are included into `PATH` for init script

Answer (score 0):

I think , we don't need sudo `sudo apt-key` and last statement would be like this ,

```
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc -O-  |sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Databricks did not find the script and the UNIX system did not like a Windows formatted file.